# How to access the loops for each

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I have the array in which I have multiple data that was fetched from database Now I am trying to access the data like that:

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comments) {
 print_r($comments);
}
```

In this first run it shows the array A. when this loop run second this shows the B

```
(A)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u] => ali
            [user_date] => 2011-01-19
            [up] => superthumb
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [u] => Lucky
        [user_date] => 2011-01-19
        [up] => superthumb
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [u] => Lucky
        [user_date] => 2011-01-19
        [up] => superthumb
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [u] => aq
        [user_date] => 2011-01-19
        [up] => cute_glassess_girl
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [u] => aq
        [user_date] => 2011-01-19
        [up] => cute_glassess_girl
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [u] => aq
        [user_date] => 2011-01-19
        [up] => cute_glassess_girl
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [u] => aq
        [user_date] => 2011-01-19
        [up] => cute_glassess_girl
    )

)
```

Here is the second array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 7
            [comment_text] => kHi there i am your great fan
            [commenter_id] => 46
            [commented_post_fk_id] => 2
            [comment_date] => 2011-01-19
            [deleted] => 0
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [comment_id] => 8
        [comment_text] => kHi there i am your great fan
        [commenter_id] => 47
        [commented_post_fk_id] => 2
        [comment_date] => 2011-01-19
        [deleted] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [comment_id] => 9
        [comment_text] => lucky0473649
        [commenter_id] => 48
        [commented_post_fk_id] => 2
        [comment_date] => 2011-01-19
        [deleted] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [comment_id] => 10
        [comment_text] => lucky0473649
        [commenter_id] => 49
        [commented_post_fk_id] => 2
        [comment_date] => 2011-01-19
        [deleted] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [comment_id] => 11
        [comment_text] => lucky0473649
        [commenter_id] => 50
        [commented_post_fk_id] => 2
        [comment_date] => 2011-01-19
        [deleted] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [comment_id] => 12
        [comment_text] => lucky0473649
        [commenter_id] => 51
        [commented_post_fk_id] => 2
        [comment_date] => 2011-01-19
        [deleted] => 0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [comment_id] => 17
        [comment_text] => ali
        [commenter_id] => 28
        [commented_post_fk_id] => 2
        [comment_date] => 2011-01-19
        [deleted] => 0
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [comment_id] => 18
        [comment_text] => ali
        [commenter_id] => 28
        [commented_post_fk_id] => 2
        [comment_date] => 2011-01-19
        [deleted] => 0
    )

)
```

I want to echo only one item Like If i want to access the comment text then it should be

```
foreach ($comments as $comments) {
 echo $comments['comment_text'];
}
```

But it's return the undefinded index

Here is the answer after json encode result:

```
[[{"u":"ali","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"superthumb"},{"u":"Lucky","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"superthumb"},{"u":"Lucky","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"superthumb"},{"u":"aq","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"cute_glassess_girl"},{"u":"aq","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"cute_glassess_girl"},{"u":"aq","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"cute_glassess_girl"},{"u":"aq","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"cute_glassess_girl"}],[{"comment_id":"7","comment_text":"kHi there i am your great fan","commenter_id":"46","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"8","comment_text":"kHi there i am your great fan","commenter_id":"47","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"9","comment_text":"lucky0473649","commenter_id":"48","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"10","comment_text":"lucky0473649","commenter_id":"49","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"11","comment_text":"lucky0473649","commenter_id":"50","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"12","comment_text":"lucky0473649","commenter_id":"51","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"17","comment_text":"ali","commenter_id":"28","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"18","comment_text":"ali","commenter_id":"28","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"}]]
```

Comment: You want to show only one item in a `array` ?

Comment: `foreach ($comments as $comment) {
 echo $comment['comment_text'];
}
`

Remove the `s` from single entity

Comment: If I change it to $comment even it returns undefined index

Comment: I want to access only comment text commentor name commentor date and comment picture name

Comment: I don't know my negative vote for what? who gave me negative should need to mention the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your json "result", you have merely created a parent array containing 2 child arrays (A & B). To access the second child, reference `[1]` in your loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4lYOX))

```
$json = '[[{"u":"ali","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"superthumb"},{"u":"Lucky","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"superthumb"},{"u":"Lucky","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"superthumb"},{"u":"aq","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"cute_glassess_girl"},{"u":"aq","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"cute_glassess_girl"},{"u":"aq","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"cute_glassess_girl"},{"u":"aq","user_date":"2011-01-19","up":"cute_glassess_girl"}],[{"comment_id":"7","comment_text":"kHi there i am your great fan","commenter_id":"46","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"8","comment_text":"kHi there i am your great fan","commenter_id":"47","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"9","comment_text":"lucky0473649","commenter_id":"48","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"10","comment_text":"lucky0473649","commenter_id":"49","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"11","comment_text":"lucky0473649","commenter_id":"50","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"12","comment_text":"lucky0473649","commenter_id":"51","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"17","comment_text":"ali","commenter_id":"28","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"},{"comment_id":"18","comment_text":"ali","commenter_id":"28","commented_post_fk_id":"2","comment_date":"2011-01-19","deleted":"0"}]]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
// var_export($array);

foreach ($array[1] as $comment) {
    echo $comment["comment_text"] , "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
kHi there i am your great fan
kHi there i am your great fan
lucky0473649
lucky0473649
lucky0473649
lucky0473649
ali
ali
```

This fixes your issue, but honestly I can't see the point of combining the arrays in a more complex structure before looping.

Answer (score 0):

So, have a look at your loop, you've set $comments as $comments, try that:

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
 echo $comment['comment_text'];
}
```

Comment: as you said I changed this to: 
foreach ($comments as $c) {
 echo $c['comment_text'];
}

Comment: still returning the same undefined index

Comment: Are you iterating over array A or array B?